# Error while copying from S3 to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to copy some files from S3 bucket to HDFS of my EMR cluster. But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running job
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:771)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://10.87.26.26:9000/tmp/33e4f3b9-d29a-49e8-9706-ea70e07e3ff2/files
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:751)
    ... 9 more
```

The command I am using is :

```
./elastic-mapreduce --jobflow  j-12345678 --jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --args '--src,s3n://my-bucket/data/,--dest,hdfs:///data/in,--srcPattern,xyz01-1-1*ped*' --step-name "Copy input files to HDFS" --wait-for-steps
```

I tried to run the sample word-count job, to check if there is any issue with HDFS, but it ran fine.

Can anyone please help me with this? If any more info is needed, please let me know and I will update the description.

Comment: Are you sure that your parameters are like in your command example? The error says that it's trying to read data from HDFS.

Comment: Yup, the command I have shown is the actual command I am running. But from the error, I thought it is trying to do some intermediate operation (since it is deleting things from /tmp directory)

Answer (score 0):

Usually its the `--srcPattern '<regex>'` argument. You can also use `hadoop fs -cp s3://src/file1.something /my/output/path/` to test for 1 file and modify your regex. Also starting with `.*` any char-0 or more times, should relax the matching.

It would be great to know if regex non-matches get logged and where.